# How do I reverse the values of a Map when one type is a Set of Integers

Tags: java, dictionary

For example how do I reverse the key and value datatypes from something like this:

```
TreeMap<Set<Integer>, Integer>
```

...into this:

```
TreeMap<Integer, Set<Integer>>
```

Comment: So you want to have a datastructre like: TreeMap<Integer, Set<Integer>> as a result?

Comment: In other words make it TreeMap<Integer, Set<Integer>>

Comment: You must be certain the values are unique.

Comment: @Robert - Update your question to include what the output is suppose to be

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Java8, you can do:

```
TreeMap<Set<Integer>, Integer> map = ....;
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> result = 
       map.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .map(entry -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey())
          .collect(Collectors.toMap());
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the entry set and put them reversely in a new TreeMap. The following generic method will reverse every map.

```
public static <K, V> TreeMap<V, K> reverse(TreeMap<K, V> map) {
    TreeMap<V, K> result = new TreeMap<V, K>();

    for (Entry<K, V> e : map.entrySet())
        result.put(e.getValue(), e.getKey());
    return result;
}
```

**Important**

If a value is present two times, you will lose the key with the smallest value.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
    map.put(1, 2);
    map.put(2, 2);
    System.out.println(reverse(map));
}
```

Output:

```
{2=2}
```

The tuple `{1,2}` is lost since the value 2 was presents multiple times!

Comment: So can I use an iterator on a set of sets of integers? Could I do something like this     Map<Set<String>, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Set<String>, Integer>();
        
        Set<Set<String>> temp = map.keySet();
        Map<Integer, Set<String>> newMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Set<String>>();
        Iterator in = temp.iterator();
        while (in.hasNext())
        {
            Set<String> temps = in.next();
            Integer temp2 = map.get(temp);
            newMap.put(temp2, temps);
        }

Comment: I iterated over the entry set of the map. The entry set stores the key/value pairs present in the Map as a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

`Map`s are not easilly reversible, And rightly so.
Reversing maps might not work.
In a `Map` Keys are obviously unique but values have no such constraint.

I don't know what the problem you're facing is, but it sounds as if there is a better design to solve it.

Perhaps you should use a `BiMap`?
It's essentialy a two way map in which both the "keys" and the "values" are unique. It allows efficient lookup both from the keys and from the values.

Java doesn't have a built in `BiMap` but [google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) and [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) do.